# MEF/PRISM Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, prism, mef

I am new to MEF/Prism and Silverlight and I am not sure how to dynamically load modules into a  ItemsControl. I basically want to be able to swap out dynamically loaded modules into the same region container. How can I do this using MEF/PRISM?

Comment: Modules aren't loaded into "Regions"! Regions are used to display "Views", which can be "discouvered" or "injected". Could you please reformulate your question and add more details? :) (by the way, the PRISM documentation along with the QuickStarts and the Reference Implementations are a good way to start ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A region to host several controls must be of type `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl 
    x:Name="MainToolbar" 
    cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.MainToolBarRegion}">
</ItemsControl>
```

Views can be added and removed by code:

```
//add view if not already present
IRegion region = this._regionManager.Regions["RegionName"];

object view = region.GetView( "ViewName" );
if ( view == null )
{
    var view = _container.ResolveSessionRelatedView<IMyView>( );
    region.Add( view, "ViewName");
}

//remove
IRegion region = this._regionManager.Regions["RegionName"];

object view = region.GetView( "ViewName" );
if ( view != null )
{
    region.Remove( view );
}
```

Using this code you could also add the views by code besides using the Prism built-in navigation functionality.

Answer (score 3):

The QuickStart project in Prism does exacly what you ask for.
It's called [Modularity QuickStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921163%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx) :)

Also, have a look at this thread: [Using Prism for navigation in Wpf application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401830/using-prism-for-navigation-in-wpf-application)

View Injection QuickStart does set a view on change of ListView selected item so might be of some help too.

Comment: This example loads MEF modules into different controls. I wanted to load many modules into 1 control Example I have a menu control that has a lot of items on it and when you click on any of the menu items it loads that specific module into 1 shared region in the shell. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, I think that it's possible. In fact I'm planning to implement it next week in my app. I think you could register all your child windows in a container (named instances), and then, on MenuItem.Clicked event Remove all Controls from a specific Region and insert the right one in place. BTW, I Use Composite Application Guidance (prev. version of Prism for Visual Studio 2008)